# Table - Number of columns based on column content length

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to achieve this (Language is not important, but I need to do it in Javascript - React):

```
|SHORT|SHORT|
|SHORT|SHORT|
|SHORT|SHORT|
|SHORT|SHORT|
| LONGTEXTT |
|   SHORT   |
| LONGTEXTT |
|SHORT|SHORT|
```

in table layout. I have array of values and when text is longer than `X` characters I need to do just one column in row.

Any finished algorithm for this?

I tried so far: Have array representing `table` with array keys what representing `rows` and his keys are `columns`. I iterated trough input array of data and whenever I filled `row` with enough cols (In this example 2) I raised row index so `table[1]` started filling. But I dont know how to continue...

Pseudocode (JS :D):

```
const inputData = ['SHORT','SHORT','LONGTEXT','SHORT'];
const maxColsPerRow = 2;

const rows = [[]];
let j = 0;
for (let col of inputData) {

  // Switch to next row if full
  if (rows[j].length === colsPerRow) j++;

  // Create new row if not exist
  if (!rows[j]) rows.push([]);

  rows[j].push(col)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look ahead to see how many items go into the next table row: If the next item is short and if there is another item after that which is short, push two items. Otherwise, just push one:

```
while (data.length) {
    let next = data.shift();

    if (isshort(next) && data.length && isshort(data[0])) {
        table.push([next, data.shift()])
    } else {
        table.push([next])
    }        
}
```

Alternatively, and perhaps more generally, you can treat this like a simple word-breaking algorithm: look whether adding the next item will overflow the current line. If yes, wrap:

```
function weight(s) {
    return (s.length < 6) ? 1 : 2;
}

const cols = 2;                       // number of columns, can be adjusted
let w = 0;                            // current weighted width of the line

for (let next of data) {
    let u = weight(next);

    if (w + u > cols) {
        table.push([]);
        w = 0;
    }

    table[table.length - 1].push(next);

    w += u;
}
```

The number of columns and the weight function can be modified to create tables with more columns.